# Passing an enum value as command parameter from XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, command

I want to pass an enum value as command parameter in WPF, using something like this:

```
<Button 
    x:Name="uxSearchButton" 
    Command="{Binding Path=SearchMembersCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="SearchPageType.First"
    Content="Search">
</Button>
```

`SearchPageType` is an enum and this is to know from which button search command is invoked.

Is this possible in WPF, or how can you pass an enum value as command parameter?

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Try this

```
<Button CommandParameter="{x:Static local:SearchPageType.First}" .../>
```

`local` - is your [namespace reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx#The_WPF_and_XAML_Namespace_Declarations) in the XAML

Answer (score 190):

Also remember that if your enum is inside another class you need to use the `+` operator.

```
<Button CommandParameter="{x:Static local:MyOuterType+SearchPageType.First}".../>
```

Answer (score 54):

You can use property element syntax instead of attribute syntax for this:

```
<Button x:Name="uxSearchButton"
        Command="{Binding Path=SearchMembersCommand}"
        Content="Search">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <SearchPageType>First</SearchPageType>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Comment: Enum name as a XAML tag? Wow, I could never suppose such syntax to work, however it does!

Answer (score 33):

Also if you want to provide a [`Flags`] enum you can use the property element syntax:

```
<Button>
  <Button.CommandParameter>
    <SearchPageType>First,Second</SearchPageType>
  <Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this[image]

CommandParameter="{x:Static "Class namespace e.g(**Models**)":SearchPageType.First}"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31278470)