# How to have an enum value in CommandParam in XAML

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, enums, command, commandparameter

I have the following enum that represent a state of UI (I use it to enable and disable UI elements):

```
enum Mode 
{
 EDIT, RUN, REVIEW
}
```

I would like to pass Mode.EDIT to command in CommandParam:

```
  <Button Grid.Column="6" VerticalAlignment="Top Command="{Binding Path=ChangeMode}" 
CommandParameter="{StaticResource local:Mode.RUN}" />
```

But I have no idea how to declare it. As you see in the button declaration, I try to use *StaticResource* but it fails. I am quite new to SL4 and C# so I suppose that I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution. I have created in my `MyViewModel` (my *DataContext*) 3 public attributes (of type Mode) and initialize them in the constructor (with values *EDIT*, *RUN*, *REVIEW*). Next, I have bound them in XAML as a normal property of a `DataContext`:

`CommandParameter="{Binding Path=EDIT}`

```
class MyViewModel
{  
  public Mode EDIT {set; get;}
  public Mode RUN {set; get;}
  public Mode REVIEW {set; get;}

  MyViewModel()
 { 
   EDIT = Mode.EDIT;
    ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In WPF we can do something like this (might not work in SL) -

```
<Button Grid.Column="6" Command="{Binding Path=ChangeMode}"
CommandParameter="{x:Static local:Mode.RUN}" />
```

check this question for more details -
[Passing an enum value as command parameter from XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359699/passing-an-enum-value-as-command-parameter-from-xaml)

Answer (score 1):

in silverlight x:Static doesn't work so we can do sth like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=ChangeMode}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <Mode>RUN</Mode>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```