# Using enum in ConverterParameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, converters

I am building an application that can be used by many users. Each user is classified to one of the next Authentication levels:

```
public enum AuthenticationEnum
{
    User,
    Technitian,     
    Administrator,
    Developer
}
```

Some controls (such as buttons) are exposed only to certain levels of users.
I have a property that holds the authentication level of the current user:

```
public AuthenticationEnum CurrentAuthenticationLevel { get; set; }
```

I want to bind this property to the 'Visibilty' property of some controls and pass a parameter to the Converter method, telling it what is the lowest authentication level that is able to see the control.
For example:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Path=CurrentAuthenticationLevel, Converter={StaticResource AuthenticationToVisibility}, ConverterParameter="Administrator"}"/>
```

means that only 'Administrator' and 'Developer' can see the button.
Unfortunately, the above code passes `"Administrator"` as a string. Of course I can use switch/case inside the converter method and convert the string to `AuthenticationEnum`. But this is ugly and prone to maintenance errors (each time the `enum` changes - the converter method would require a change also).

Is there a better way to pass a nontrivial object as a parameter?

Comment: Make the Fredrik's answer as answered Please.

Comment: See this for other formats and more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359699/passing-an-enum-value-as-command-parameter-from-xaml

Answer (score 103):

ArsenMkrt's answer is correct,

Another way of doing this is to use the `x:Static` syntax in the `ConverterParameter`

```
<Button ...
        Visibility="{Binding Path=CurrentAuthenticationLevel,
            Converter={StaticResource AuthenticationToVisibility},
            ConverterParameter={x:Static local:AuthenticationEnum.Administrator}}"/>
```

And in the converter

```
public class AuthenticationToVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        AuthenticationEnum authenticationEnum = (AuthenticationEnum)parameter;
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we do it in Windows Store Apps? Seems like x:Static is not recognizable by this project type.

Answer (score 8):

User

```
 (AuthenticationEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(AuthenticationEnum),parameter)
```

to parse string as enumerator

Comment: Using enum value directly has better performance than parsing string every time?