# IValueConverter removing underlying value of enum(int)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, enums, ivalueconverter

I'm passing an `Enum` with underlying value (`int`) as a parameter from `XAML` to an `IValueConverter`. The idea is to use the `Enum` value to iterate against a list to check if the value exists & return a `Visibility` `enum`. The list is of type `int`. But when passing the `Enum` to the `converter`, I cannot cast the `Enum` back to an `int`. 
Peering into the parameter with 'Quick Watch', I cannot see the underlying value or any value at all.

Enum e.g.

```
public class Operations
{
    public enum Reporting
    {
        ReportAccounts    = 101,
        ReportEngineering = 102,
        ReportSoftware    = 103,
        ReportPR          = 104,
        ReportCRM         = 105
     }
     public enum Editing
     {
        EditUser   = 201,
        EditAccess = 202,
        EditView   = 203
     }
 }
```

XAML e.g.

```
Visibility={Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter={x:Static Operations:Reporting.ReportAccounts}}
```

`IValueConverter` e.g.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
     bool visibility = OperationList.Exists(list => list.Id == (int)parameter);
     if (visibility == true)
     {
         return Visibility.Visible;
     }
     else
     {
         return Visibility.Collapsed;
     }
 }
```

I would like to know if there is any way of retaining or retrieving the underlying value of an enum when it is passed to an `IValueConverter`.

Comment: You say you are peering into *value*, but you pass the enum value as the `ConverterParameter`. Have you tried peering into `parameter` instead?

Comment: Please format your source code properly. That formatting had already been done - not only in your code samples, but also in your message text - by a fellow SO user, but you just undid those changes and thereby made your question considerably less readable.

Comment: is there a way to recall this post? I haven't really formatted the question? this is my first post.

Comment: Yes, see under your quesiton, where it says "edited ..." - that's a link that brings you to the editing history of your question :-) You can see diffs for each editing operation done so far.

Comment: Found an earlier question that is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942501/using-enum-in-converterparameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to cast the parameter to the enum-type `Reporting` first:

```
int val = System.Convert.ToInt32((Reporting)parameter);
bool visibility = OperationList.Exists(list => list.Id == val);
```