# Passing an enum value as command parameter when using MultiBinding

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, command

I want to do something similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359699/passing-an-enum-value-as-command-parameter-from-xaml) but using MultipleBindings.

So something like this:

```
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource commandParametersConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding Path="DataContext" />
                <Binding Path="{x:Static vm:Direction.Down}" Mode="OneWay"/>
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
```

The line:

```
    <Binding Path="{x:Static vm:Direction.Down}" Mode="OneWay"/>
```

Throws error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I assume a static is not permitted in this context, so what's the next best option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `Path` to `Source` in `<Binding Path="{x:Static vm:Direction.Down}" Mode="OneWay"/>`:

```
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource commandParametersConverter}">
        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
            <Binding Path="DataContext" />
            <Binding Source="{x:Static vm:Direction.Down}" Mode="OneWay"/>
        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```