# how to pass an enum value to a multi-parameters RelayCommand (WPF / MVVM)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Working on a WPF / MVVM project.
Still a noob at XAML.
I do not manage to pass an enum parameter to a RelayCommand

```
public enum MyEnum {Val1, Val2, Val3};
```

xaml part:

```
<Button   Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
   <Button.CommandParameter>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                <!-- all my other parameters that wok fne-->
                <Binding  Path="{StaticResource MyEnum.Val1}"/>
          </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>RelayCommand
```

which is declared as a resource this way:

```
  <vm:MyEnum x:Key="MyEnum " />
```

What id I miss?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/360076/869621 (not marking it as a duplicate because I don't know if multi-parameters commands work the same way, but I see no reason why not)

Comment: What is "multi-parameters RelayCommand"? Could you post a declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Either the blank at the end of your resourcekey is the problem or you could try the following:

```
{x:Static vm:MyEnum.Val1}"
```

EDIT:

To clarify this Snippet:

```
<Binding  Path="{x:Static vm:MyEnum.Val1}"/>
```

But if you are always binding the same value, you can also put that enumvalue as constant in your converter.

Comment: this way you mean?
  <Binding  Path="{x:Static vm:MyEnum.Val1}"}/>
It is not accepted ("Key cannot be null").